# How to run aggregation on current page data in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to narrow aggregation input (data on which it will be run) to documents that are in current page, limited by `from` and `size` from the query?

Comment: can you show your current query

Comment: From and size only limit the number of hits that are returned but aggregations always run on the whole result set that matches the query.